# Unable to identify unicode of Greek letter

Tags: greek

I am having problem identifying the unicode for the last character in the following Greek phrase (using the Greek TTL font):
[image]

(I am trying to convert a document using Greek TTL to Unicode. I have consulted Greek Unicode tables on the Internet but have failed to convert the said character.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the letter `ῦ`, aka `GREEK SMALL LETTER UPSILON WITH PERISPOMENI, U+1FE6`.

The *perispōmenē/perispomeni* accent, literally "circumflex", has two different forms in Greek depending on the font. Some fonts render it like a Latin circumflex, `û`. Others render it like a Latin tilde, `ũ`. But the meaning is the same either way, and Unicode doesn't distinguish the two.

The phrase is *βίοι Ἰησοῦ*, literally "lives of Jesus". You seem to have picked up an extra accent mark, too, which is overlapping with the beta at the beginning.